# String-boot: UriComponentsBuilder '#' replaced by `%23'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm running against an issue I guess it has to be easy to solve but I'm stuck on.

This is my code snippet:

```
String path = "#/we-transfer";
URI downloadReferenceUiURI = 
    UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(this.apiProperties.getUrlUi())
    .path(path + "/{id}")
    .build("sampleid");

String url = downloadReferenceUiURI.toString();
String url2 = downloadReferenceUiURI.toASCIIString();
```

The value of `url` and `url2` is:

```
http://localhost/%23/we-transfer/sampleid
```

As you can see, `#` character is replaced by `%23`.

Any ideas about how to solve that?

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode( url, "UTF-8" )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's encoded, you can decode it mannually:

```
String url = URLDecoder.decode(downloadReferenceUiURI.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: It keeps replacing `#` by `%23`. What I need to get is `http://localhost/#/we-transfer/sampleid`...

Comment: @Jordi Have you tired both?

Comment: Sorry, the first one works, but the lastest doesn't.